# Changing phones from iPhone 7 Plus to iPhone X leaves many contacts unsync'd

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, contacts

I used the backup/restore via iTunes to set up my new iPhone X. It's missing hundreds of my contacts. I use iCloud to store my contacts, photos, etc, but alas they are not all sync'd.

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Contacts work in a confusing way because you may not simply have just one set of contacts.   Open the contacts app then click “groups” and make sure all the “groups” are selected.   If you still have old phone do the same there and compare.

Comment: Additional info: contacts are stored as part of your email account.  If you have multiple email accounts you will also have multiple contact files.

Comment: iCloud doesn't sync all content in 1 shot.  It could take 24 hours, sometimes longer, for all your data to sync.  Wait a few days, make sure all your contacts are in iCloud and all your accounts are setup properly.